# What does the ⇒ mean in Context Free Grammer? Also, how do I derive/get the L(CFG) from a CFG?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I'm a bit confused. Does the ⇒ simply denote you going through the CFG step by step
? To use a pretty basic-ish example:

sentence ⇒ subject | predicate

subject ⇒ article | noun 
predicate ⇒ verb | direct object
article ⇒ THE | A
noun ⇒ CAT | MAN

And so on and so forth? Is the above an L(CFG)?

Comment: I invite you to read the Wikipedia entry [Context-free grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and in particular the section *Production rule notation*.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thank you. Would you say that what I wrote above is similar to the L(CFG) described here?